# How to get array of strings or integers from users inside looping statement?

Tags: java

When I tried to run this code `noOfSub()` methods executed properly;
but `GC()` method faces the following problem:

```
Enter the number of subjects:
2
Enter Your Subject 1 Grade:
s
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at GPA.GC(GPA.java:21)
    at GPA.main(GPA.java:35)
Java Result: 1
```

Here is my code:

```
 import java.util.Scanner;  

 public class GPA {   

   public int noOfSubjects;  
   public int i=1;
   Scanner gradeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
   String[] grade = new String[noOfSubjects];
   int[] credit = new int[noOfSubjects];

    public void noOfSub() {
        System.out.println("Enter the number of subjects:");
        Scanner sub = new Scanner(System.in);
        noOfSubjects = sub.nextInt();   
    } 
    public void GC() {
        while(i<=noOfSubjects)
        {
          System.out.println("Enter Your Subject "+i+" Grade:" );

            grade[i] = gradeInput.nextLine();

            System.out.println("Enter the Subject "+i+" Credit:");

            credit[i] = gradeInput.nextInt();
                i++;              
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       GPA obj = new GPA();
       obj.noOfSub();
       obj.GC();
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in your array initialization. You can initialize your array after take the input from user.

For example :

```
public void noOfSub() {
  System.out.println("Enter the number of subjects:");
  Scanner sub = new Scanner(System.in);
  noOfSubjects = sub.nextInt();   
  grade = new String[noOfSubjects];
  credit = new int[noOfSubjects];
}
```

And change your while condition. Instead of this you use

```
  while(i < noOfSubjects)
```

and set `i = 0`

Answer (score 1):

When you do:

```
public int noOfSubjects;
```

`noOfSubjects` is set to `0` which is its `default value`

So when you have the following code:

```
 String[] grade = new String[noOfSubjects];
```

it essentially means,

```
String[] grade = new String[0]; //create a new String array with size 0
```

which creates an empty array for you.

So when you do,

```
grade[i] = gradeInput.nextLine(); //where i is 1
```

you get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at GPA.GC(GPA.java:21)
    at GPA.main(GPA.java:35
```

because there is no index `1` in `String[] grade`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the size for the array from the user, create the array after getting it from stdin. Otherwise it will create a array with the size of 0 which is the default value for int in java.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your declaration and  initalization

```
String[] grade = null;
int[] credit = null;
...
noOfSubjects = scan.nextInt();
grade = new String[noOfSubjects];
credit = new int[noOfSubjects];
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) because the size of array isn't know for you

```
public class GPA {   

 public int noOfSubjects;  
 public int i=0;
 Scanner gradeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
 List<String> grade = new ArrayList<>();
 List<Integer> credit = new ArrayList<>();

    public void noOfSub(){
        System.out.println("Enter the number of subjects:");
        Scanner sub = new Scanner(System.in);
        noOfSubjects = sub.nextInt();   
    } 
    public void GC(){
        while(i<noOfSubjects)
        {
          System.out.println("Enter Your Subject "+(i+1)+" Grade:" );

            grade.add(gradeInput.nextLine());

            System.out.println("Enter the Subject "+(i+1)+" Credit:");

            credit.add(gradeInput.nextInt());
            gradeInput.nextLine(); 
                i++;              
        }
    }
            public static void main(String[] args) {
               GPA obj = new GPA();
               obj.noOfSub();
               obj.GC();
            }  
    }
```

**Note** : i added `gradeInput.nextLine()` after `i++` because  the `Scanner.nextInt()` method does not consume the last newline character of your input, and thus that newline is consumed in the next call to `Scanner.nextLine()` so i fire a blank `gradeInput.nextLine()` call after `gradeInput.nextInt()` to consume rest of that line including newline

Answer (score 0):

Since the noOfSubjects has run time value so the code should be:

import java.util.Scanner;

public class GPA {

```
public int noOfSubjects;
public int i = 0;
Scanner gradeInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String[] grade;
int[] credit;

public void noOfSub() {
    System.out.println("Enter the number of subjects:");
    Scanner sub = new Scanner(System.in);
    noOfSubjects = sub.nextInt();
    grade = new String[noOfSubjects];
    credit = new int[noOfSubjects];
}

public void GC() {

    while (i < noOfSubjects) {
        System.out.println("Enter Your Subject " + (i + 1) + " Grade:");

        grade[i] = gradeInput.next();

        System.out.println("Enter the Subject " + (i + 1) + " Credit:");

        credit[i] = gradeInput.nextInt();
        i++;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < grade.length; j++) {
        System.out.println(grade[j] + " " + credit[j]);
    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GPA obj = new GPA();
    obj.noOfSub();
    obj.GC();
}
```

}